# Android Jetpack Compose opening DefaultPreview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When I debug my Jetpack Compose app in Android Studio, it always tries to open DefaultPreview of the app.
I want to launch MainActivity, which inherits from `ComponentActivity`.

If I close the app and relaunch it solely on my phone, `MainActivity` is opened, but now I can't debug in Android Studio.

When I delete the `@DefaultPreview`, the app won't build at all, because it failed to find this Preview.
If I keep the Preview, this is then opened on the phone and I can't use Hilt, or navigation to navigate to the screen I want to go to.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by removing Compose Preview from Run Configuration

[image: Select Edit Configurations from the configurations dialog]

[image: Press - button to Remove selected configuration]

[image: Correct list of configurations]